# Angularjs setting value in Factory from resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory in which I have **post** and **comments** properties which values are values from my resource object. But when I try to call **getComment()** function it still returns [];

**my factory**
    angular.module('flapperNews').factory('postService', ['$resource', function($resource){

```
    var service = {};
    var postId = 0;
    var post = {};
    var comments = [];

    service.resource = function() {
        return $resource('api/posts/:id.json', {id: "@id"},
        {
            'create':  { method: 'POST' },
            'index':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
            'show':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
            'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
            'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
        }
        );
    };

    service.setPost = function(postId) {
        this.resource().show({id: postId}, function(post) {
            post = post;
            comments = post.comments;
        });
    };

    service.getComments = function() {
        return comments;
    };
    service.setPostId = function(newPostId) {
        this.postId = newPostId;
    };

    return service;

}]);
```

**usage in my controller**

```
....
function ($scope, Post, Comment, $stateParams, formlyValidationMessages, Page,     Auth, loginForm, postService) {

    postService.setPost($stateParams.id);
    console.log(postService.getComments());
    ....
```

Comment: Show the code which uses the get comments, it has to be done only after the promise is resolved

Comment: it's shown below "usage in my controller"

Comment: did you debug the setPost call? is there any value in post.comments? do you wait with "getComments" untill the promise is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is async and you try to use synchronously,
change that function to

```
 service.setPost = function(postId) {
        return this.resource().show({id: postId}).$promise.then(function(post) {
            post = post;
            comments = post.comments;
        });
    };
```

and in the controller -

```
postService.setPost($stateParams.id).then(function(){
     console.log(postService.getComments());
});
```

that way it should work! 
because we wait for the comments property to be filled.

good luck

Comment: Ok but what if I want to access service comments property from another controller? and I just want to use (postService.comments)?

Comment: Tell me more about the flow of the controllers and the usage of the comments in you're app, so I can help you find the solution

Comment: I have post page with post details (title, content) and comments. for displaying post details and comments I have postCtrl and for my (create comment form) I have commentCtrl. The thing is that when I create new comment in my CommentCtrl I want to add new created comments to already created array of comments so it would show up in the page.

Comment: you can assume the array has already been created because the flow dictates it happens after the setPost function was called. just call the function that adds comments and it should work fine.